# Access Legend attributes in Seaborn set_style()

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I've been experimenting with `sns.set_style()` to limit redundantly setting plot attributes.
The problem I'm encountering is that I can't seem to find how to access all of the attributes that I'd like to modify, .e.g. legend color.

See below style sheet and plotting code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

dark_plot_no_tick = {
    'axes.facecolor': '#181818',
    'legend.facecolor': "white", # still inheriting from figure
    'axes.edgecolor': '1',
    'axes.grid': False,
    'figure.facecolor': '#181818', # Works inline but not saving
    'xtick.bottom': False, # still visible
    'xtick.top': False,
    'ytick.left': False, # still visible
    'ytick.right': False,
    'axes.spines.left': True,
    'axes.spines.bottom': True,
    'axes.spines.right': False,
    'axes.spines.top': False
}

sns.set_style(rc=dark_plot_no_tick)
sns.set_palette(['#5FB7B2'])

fig, ax = plt.pyplot.subplots()
sns.kdeplot(np.random.normal(10, 10, 10_000), label="test", ax=ax)
fig.savefig("test.png");
```

The only problem is the legend facecolor is either transparent or inheriting and I can't figure out how to change it in the style sheet that I'm passing to set_style().

Here what it looks like now:

[Incorrectly formatted legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY074.png)

And this is what I'd like it to look like:

[Correctly formatted legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyGmb.png)

Edit:
As per @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's suggestion I've tried the below:

```
import matplotlib 

matplotlib.rcParams["legend.facecolor"] = "white"
matplotlib.rcParams["xtick.bottom"] = False
matplotlib.rcParams["ytick.left"] = False
```

Using `rcParams` to modify `legend.facecolor` works while it does not work to modify `xtick.bottom` and `ytick.left`.

That said, I would still prefer to modify the facecolor using `sns.set_style()` rather than with `matplotlib.rcParams`.

Also, I realize removing ticks was not part of the original issue, but I've included it here as I believe the two might be giving issues due to the same root cause.

Comment: Use `legend.facecolor`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've tried changing `legend.facecolor` from `inherit` to a range of things (e.g. values 0-1, hex color codes, etc) and it never works.

Comment: Can you check if `plt.rcParams["legend.facecolor"] = "red"` works within your script? If it does, it means you have an error in your style file; so best show the style file in the question.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest would have sworn on my life that I tried that... It's working that way and when I update using rc_params using `rc={"legend.facecolor": "white"}`. 
Thanks!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest this is extremely strange... `c={"legend.facecolor": "white"}` is no longer working but `plt.rcParams["legend.facecolor"] = "red"` still works... And `plt.savefig()` and `fig.savefig()` aren't necessarily consistent with each other or what is rendered in jupyter.  

Am I just experiencing some strange edge-case?

Comment: Also, experiencing similar issues with things like setting `xtick.color`/`ytick.color` and `xtick.bottom`/`ytick.left` but `plt.rcParams["xtick.bottom"] = False` doesn't even take care of it.

Comment: It's hard for anyone to even have a slight clue of what you're talking about here without [mcve].

Comment: Apologies @ImportanceOfBeingErnest; let me know if the above is sufficient.

Comment: Can you confirm that it works when replacing  `sns.set_style(rc=dark_plot_no_tick)` with `plt.rcParams.update(dark_plot_no_tick)` though?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest `plt.rcParams.update(dark_plot_no_tick)` solves the issue with the legend!  However, the `xticks` and `yticks` are still visible. Should I make a new post for that?

Comment: You can, but mind that the ticks issue is not reproducible for me. So when doing so try to give much more information about system/versions/how you run code etc. Else, I fear noone would be able to help.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm using Python `3.7.6`, seaborn `0.10.0`, and matplotlib `3.2.0`. I've run the above code in jupyter, iPython, and as a python script and am having the same issue with ticks in each. If it helps I'm on mac Catalina version `10.15.3`.